# Move program to other submenu on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, pixel

In the Raspberry Pi menu (the "Start"-like interface you get by pressing Super aka Windows key) there are programs organized in folders (or submenus) depending on their category.

The Pi is going to be used at school and *Musescore* will be used to teach, not to play music, so I don't think *A/V* is the right category for that program.

Instead, I'd like to move it to the *Education* tab that appeared after installing *GeoGebra*.

I'm running Raspbian Jessie with *Pixel Desktop* on Raspberry Pi 3. I have Internet connection and a lot of free space, so I can install programs if needed.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the start menu (I, too, just learned it's apparently called start menu..) and find your program. Right click allows you to select `Properties`.

In the window that opens, you find a line labeled `Target file` which specifies the path to this application's .desktop file which determines the menu-subcategory.

Open said target file (e.g. using `nano /path/to/target/file.desktop`) and change the line labeled `Categories`. It should continue to contain "Application", but the other entry should change from whatever it is right now to (probably) "Education". Unfortunately, I have neither an Education nor an A/V submenu, so I don't know the exact phrases - but if this doesn't work, you can just open the target file for the application GeoGebra and simply copy the Categories-line.

After saving the change, the application should move to the new submenu.

Comment: Thanks! I too thought it could have to do with the .desktop file, but I was unsure on the lines to edit